# Cannot kill Bull and Gouger in the quest "Confidence Man"

Tags: fallout-4

I am inside the brewery with Travis but I cannot kill Bull or Gouger. They seem to be marked as essential, as when I kill them they simply just lay down for a while then get back up good as new. I don't really want to use the console or cheat by modifying the quest stage, is there another way to get around this bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the issue was that I was playing on a 144HRz monitor and things can get [pretty weird](https://i.imgur.com/aD7eICO.gifv) when playing at >60HRz on the Gamebryo engine.

I temporarily lowered my monitors refresh rate back down to 60, loaded a prior quicksave before I entered the brewery, and was able to kill Bull and Gouger.

Comment: Well *that's* odd. Are you sure it was actually the refresh rate and not just loading the prior save?

Comment: @DCShannon I tried that one first, it is odd I know but it's what worked for me.

Comment: Please note that on May 15, 2023, [Imgur will remove content that is not tied to a user account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388556/162827). This may affect the media you included in your post since it was not uploaded through SE Imgur. I recommend that you reupload the media through SE Imgur to avoid losing it. You may need to edit the media to make it smaller than 2 MiB, which is the maximum size allowed by SE Imgur.

Comment: @galacticninja probably should just remove the link to the gif.  It's not really relevant. And there is no way we can get that shortened down to 2Mb without completely losing most of the animation.

Comment: @TimmyJim I agree, it’s not really relevant. I don’t think it’s worth backing up either. We can just let it be until it eventually gets deleted (or a GIF expert can cut it down to little 2 MiB pieces).